# Silent Administrative Install - Specifying an installation directory

Tags: command-line, installation, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm currently trying to add some testing functionality into our builds, and in order to do this I need to be able to perform an administrative install, silently. However, I need to be able to specify the location that it installs too, as the default is on the company-wide network which is no use.

I was wondering if there was a way to specify the installation directory through parameters for this type of operation, and if so how?

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 12, accepted):

msiexec /a foo.msi TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT\ /qn /l*v admin_install.log

/a = admin install of foo.msi
/qn  fully silent ( /qb! is mostly silent )
/l*v create a verbose log - in case it fails

Comment: So, If i don't use TARGETDIR . Will it throw an error or is there a default directory? TIA !

Comment: It depends on the MSI. Best to find out on a VM.

Comment: @user2048204 It may simply copy files to `C:/ProgramFilesFolder`

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Is there any way to control which feature the installer will unpack from the MSI? The installer creates a `ProgramFilesFolder` with all files and also creates an empty MSI.

Comment: After administrative install of MSI+MSP using /a, is there a specific way to install subsequent msp(hotfixes).

Comment: This question is 10 years old.  Please ask a new question.  That said, no there isn't.  The application must be uninstalled/reinstalled to get the latest patches to the administrative installation point.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me you should just set `TARGETDIR` or `INSTALLDIR` property in the command line during starting of `msiexec.exe`: like `TARGETDIR=C:\MyDir` or `INSTALLDIR=C:\MyDir` as additional `msiexec.exe` parameter.